# Typescript/Hapi: Property 'example' does not exist on type 'PluginProperties'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, hapi.js, hapi

Ii I have a hapi plugin such as the one below:

```
exports.plugin = {
    name: 'example',
    register: function (server, options) {

        server.expose('key', 'value');

        console.log(server.plugins.example.key);      // 'value'
    }
};
```

I can see that the plugin is exposed in a route handler, however when I try to access that value using:

```
async handler(request: Request, h: ResponseToolkit) {
      const value = request.server.plugins.example.key;
```

I have a typescript error `Property 'example' does not exist on type 'PluginProperties'.`

How do I add this and other plugins to the hapi type?

Comment: By removing `"strict": true" from tsconfig, this removed the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define PluginProperties fields and types by extending hapi module in *types/hapi/index.d.ts*:

```
declare module 'hapi' {
  export interface PluginProperties {
    [key: string]: any; // TODO define
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend the existing type and then ideally cast your Request to it.

```
import { PluginProperties } from '@hapi/hapi';

interface IExtendedPluginProperties extends PluginProperties {
  example: {
    key: any; // define your strict types here instead of `any`
  }
};
```

Then inside your handler...

```
async handler(request: Request, h: ResponseToolkit) {
  const { key } = (<IExtendedPluginProperties>request.server.plugins).example;
}
```

PS. The accepted answer is wrong, what `Andrej Leitner` is suggesting is literally overriding the existing Hapi types. When you update to newest version of Hapi this will be gone or inaccurate. You should never override, use `extend` instead.